# Verbo "sfuggire": una stessa idea si può esprimere sia in modo transitivo che in modo intransitivo?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Quando il [verbo "sfuggire"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sfuggire/) ha la funzione transitiva è coniugato con l'ausiliare "avere", ma quando ha invece la funzione intransitiva viene costruito con l'ausiliare "essere". La mia domanda è, se con questo verbo, una stessa idea si potrebbe esprimere sia in modo transitivo che in modo intransitivo. Ad esempio:

> - Lo squalo ha sfuggito la presa del pescatore e si è allontanato.
> - Lo squalo è sfuggito alla presa del pescatore e si è allontanato.
> - Il pescatore ha sfuggito il pericolo.
> - Il pescatore è sfuggito al pericolo.

Se entrambe le forme sono corrette, esiste qualche differenza di uso tra le due? Per esempio, una di queste costruzioni potrebbe essere molto formale o caduta piuttosto in disuso.

Comment: Ha sfuggito vs è sfuggito: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avere+sfuggito%2Cessere+sfuggito%2Cha+sfuggito%2C+%C3%A8+sfuggito&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavere%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cessere%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cha%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A8%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "La mia domanda è, se con questo verbo, una stessa idea si potrebbe esprimere sia in modo transitivo che in modo intransitivo"; beh ti sei un pò risposta da sola con "Quando il verbo "sfuggire" ha la funzione transitiva è coniugato con l'ausiliare "avere", ma quando ha invece la funzione intransitiva viene costruito con l'ausiliare "essere"": si può esprimere la stessa cosa sia in modo transitivo che intransitivo cambiando l'ausiliare; quindi corrette sono certamente corrette tutte e due, ma come Josh61 ha evidenziato "ha sfuggito" è molto meno utilizzata

Comment: @kos: Se è così, potresti scriverlo in una risposta?

Comment: Certamente, forse avrei dovuto farlo subito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quando il verbo "sfuggire" ha la funzione transitiva è coniugato con l'ausiliare "avere", ma quando ha invece la funzione intransitiva viene costruito con l'ausiliare "essere"

Questo è vero, [come Treccani stesso cita](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sfuggire/), quindi direi che ogni dubbio sulla correttezza grammaticale di tutte le forme citate possa essere fugato senza problemi.

Assodato il fatto che entrambi i costrutti sono di per se corretti, resta da vedere quanto rientrino in un uso contemporaneo e comune della lingua; analizzando (molto brevemente) il [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avere+sfuggito%2Cessere+sfuggito%2Cha+sfuggito%2C+%C3%A8+sfuggito&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavere%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cessere%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cha%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A8%20sfuggito%3B%2Cc0) nel commento postato da Josh61 è palese la differenza nell'uso dei due e come questa sia andata ad accrescersi nel tempo (e, per quel che vale dopo una prova così robusta, anche a me "avere sfuggito il" suona molto peggio di "essere sfuggito al", in tutte le coniugazioni).

Quindi sono decisamente corrette tutte e due, ma altrettanto decisamente "avere sfuggito il" suona molto peggio di "essere sfuggito al", il che probabilmente è dovuto al molto più largo utilizzo (specialmente ad oggi) della seconda forma; quindi, se puoi, ti suggerisco di usare quella.